# Add ability to enter the close vote review queue directly from search results

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, vote-to-close

### Motivation

So, you've found yourself [a nice set of search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22best+tool%22+closed%3Ano), of which probably 99% of the questions need to be closed. Awesome, right? Not quite.

For anyone who's cast a few close votes (or flags) on old questions, and followed up on some of them, you know that these rarely go anywhere (unless you happen to be a moderator) (because of the close vote queue numbers).

Thus, in order for us common folk to effectively close old questions, we need teamwork.

And what better way to get teamwork than to simply be able to post a direct link to a magical place where a list of the above questions are ready and waiting in a simple and easy to deal with format?

Which brings me to...

### Proposal

I propose that we **allow users to enter the close vote review queue from any search page** (which will then show questions only from those search results).

- Phase 1: Show only questions with close votes or flags (similar to the way it works now).
- Phase 2: Add an option to show all the open questions (for those search results).

### How this could be implemented (first draft)

Put a "review" link on the search page. Possibly add the number of questions needing review in brackets.

[image]

Maybe the "filter" button should be disabled, hidden [or just not work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231436/changing-the-filter-in-the-close-vote-queue-doesnt-work-when-having-gotten-ther).

[image]

**For phase 2**:

We can possibly replace the "filter" button with a toggle button:

[image]

[image]

(not sure about the naming here)

And, on open questions, <kbd>Leave Open</kbd> either does the same as <kbd>Skip</kbd>, or is disabled.

Comment: What efficiency is there to gain from this? You are asking for queues within queues. I'm naturally sceptical of voting rings (even ones that have good intentions) but you can already publish your search results as a link, your CVR can then visit each question and cast votes that way.

Comment: How about a better way to vet those results and compile a list of only those you vetted this time instead? So, a way to get a list of links to all questions you delete-voted resp. close-voted and/or flagged for closing/deletion in $time-window? Just add some initial motivating paragraphs and mention the still outstanding work, and you are nearly done. Bonus points if the reader can filter it according what he can/should act on now, possibly making it a custom close/delete-queue, with option to disagree and kick it out. That might even make things more efficient... Still, no idea how much work.